gitlab-runner cannot check jobs when its container stops
I have a more complex setup where gitlab-runner itself runs in AWS ECS as a container in a service task. The container entrypoint itself handles runner registration and deregistration. Workers are spawned as EC2 instances via docker+machine. We are "leaking" EC2 machines that are not terminated when the runner service shuts down.
When the gitlab-runner container shuts down, I see this:
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=warning msg="[runWait] received stop signal" builds=0 max_builds=1 stop-signal=quit
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=warning msg="Starting graceful shutdown, waiting for builds to finish" StopSignal=quit builds=0 max_builds=1
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=warning msg="Checking for jobs... failed" runner=FcpdW2x9A status="couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request: Post \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request\": context canceled"
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=info msg="All workers stopped." builds=0 max_builds=1
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=info msg="Shutting down executor providers" builds=0 max_builds=1 shutdown-timeout=30s
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=info msg="All executor providers shut down." builds=0 max_builds=1
time="2024-10-03T18:33:27Z" level=info msg="Can exit now!" builds=0 max_builds=1
Unregistering runner at https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/41665618

I believe our failure to kill EC2 workers automatically might be related to the failure to check for jobs.
The GitLab API failure is trivial to reproduce:

register a runner
make a config.toml for the registered runner and put it in ./config/config.toml
run the gitlab-runner image with:

docker run -it --rm --name gr \
  -v `pwd`/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

Then CTRL-\ the container. You will get the same error:
WARN[0040] Checking for jobs... failed                   runner=Jv6Po1Dbp status="couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request: Post \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request\": context canceled"

What can I do to allow gitlab-runner to run in a container, register itself, dispatch jobs to workers, then actually handle the container shutdown gracefully?
